# ui-sref not working in nested views

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-router

Homework I've done - reviewed almost 8-9 ui-sref related questions (how to, complex examples, etc.) on this site, the related plunks, Scotch.io, etc. I can't seem to figure why my code is not working. I've spent 6-7 hours debugging the app and I can't seem to find the issue.

My page is divided into
a) layout.html - this forces the bootstrap grid system
b) app-navbar - nav bar on top (code is cut-n-paste of bootstrap example for now...)
c) app-accordion - uses the ui bootstrap accordion to display n number of items
d) app-right - right side comprises some UI elements and a ui-grid

The ui-view for all elements render correctly ... i.e., the "index" state is being called in my controller. I added a couple of simple buttons in app-navbar.html just to debug...

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a ui-sref="view1">View1</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a ui-sref="view2">View2</a></li>
</ul>
<div ui-view="view-test"></div>
```

here's a snippet of my controller code:

```
        .state('view1', {
            url: '/view1',
            views: {
                'view-test': {
                    templateUrl: 'view1.html',
                    controller: 'View1Ctrl'
                }
            }
        })
```

When I hover over the buttons, I see that the .../view1 and 2 show up on the browser's footer but when I click them nothing happens. For now, the accordion still uses href but it stops working if I use ui-sref. Once I get past this, that's the next question ... how do you use ui-sref for controls like accordion?

Any ideas on what might be going on? The plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/c89j3eFvYyguMt0QznAI

Answer (score 1):

There is [updated working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NYmLAoOM6QDl1wKqoV6S?p=preview). I made 2 changes.

Firstly I upgraded your [version to UI-Router 0.2.13](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/releases) *(fixes some issues, simply always use the latest)*

Secondly, I added the missing piece in state defintion: *who is my parent*

```
.state('view1', {
    url: '/view1',
    parent: 'index',        // here is explicit setting who is parent
    views: {
        'view-test': {
            templateUrl: 'view1.html',
            controller: 'View1Ctrl'
        }
    }
})
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NYmLAoOM6QDl1wKqoV6S?p=preview)

EXTENDED, based on the comment below, with few cites from documentation

### [Methods for Nesting States](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)

> States can be nested within each other. There are several ways of nesting states:
>
> - Using *'dot notation'*. For example `.state('contacts.list', {})`.
> - Use the `ui-router.stateHelper` to build states from a nested state tree. Courtesy of @marklagendijk.
> - Using the **`parent`** property with the parent name as string. For example: **`parent: 'contacts'`**
> - Using the **`parent`** property with the parent object. For example parent: contacts (where 'contacts' is a stateObject)

...

#### [`Parent` Property using State Name String](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#parent-property-using-state-name-string)

> Alternately, you can specify the parent of a state via the parent property.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('contacts', {})
  .state('list', {
    parent: 'contacts'
  });
```

Comment: Radim - thank you very much. Is there any documentation on the parent property? I don't see that here http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api or in most of the examples on this site. Was there something different in my code structure?

Comment: Also, I noticed that with this change, the accordion stops working.

Comment: I extende answer with documentation cites and link. Does it help? I can hardly judg about accordion, it is not related to UI-Router and would not say that it was working without my fixes....

Comment: Radim - the documentation helps! I'll debug the accordion separately.