# AngularJS ui-sref not working on Andriod phone

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am experiencing a problem when trying to test my [portfolio website](http://lastanton.com/#!/projects) on my mother’s mobile (Samsung Galaxy JS 3).  The images and titles of the projects get loaded onto the index page from JSON with ng-repeat and the links to the information are made from the project IDs with ui-sref.  The website loads on the mobile all right and it can direct to the about page, which also uses ui-sref, but it cannot direct to the child pages – it either stays on the main page, or if I force it to go to one of the pages, it displays a blank page with a toggle menu (ng-include header).

It works fine on a Sony Xperia M4, Samsung Galaxy Young, Galaxy A5, my desktop computer (Windows 8.1) and a Mac (not sure about the operating system).  I’ve followed the [“Hello Solarsystem” tutorial](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/tutorial/hellosolarsystem), which also seems to have the same issue when I tried the Plunker version of it on her phone this morning (7th of June).
I have ensured that the site was using the most up to date version after reading [ui-sref not working in nested views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073820/ui-sref-not-working-in-nested-views), I’ve tried adding ui-view to the template that displays the project’s links as is advised on here: [Ui-sref not generating clickable links/not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27594132/ui-sref-not-generating-clickable-links-not-working) and I am now feeling stuck.

Sorry if my question is a bit long, but I've never had to write one before and I don't want to miss anything.

EDIT: I have now made a plunk with the exact code I'm using for the projects - [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A9oPa5?p=preview) and I have now removed ui-router, so it does not load the inner page as a sub page, but at least is viewable in all browsers - the plunk is using ui-router.

The code that I'm thinking has issues is being listed below.

**projects.html - view**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 project-block" ng-repeat="project in $ctrl.projects">
            <a ui-sref="project({ projectId: project.id })" ui-sref-active="active">
                <div class="grid-item university">
                    <div class="grid-caption">
                        <img ng-src="{{project.thumb}}" alt="{{project.name}} ({{project.desc}})" id="portfolio-thumb-{{project.id}}" />
                        <div class="titles">
                            <div class="grid-projects title">{{project.name}}</div>
                            <div class="grid-projects desc">{{project.desc}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="myPortfolio">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header ng-include="'header.html'"></header>
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>
            <ui-view></ui-view>
            <uir-state-vis class="statevis" width="300" height="100"></uir-state-vis>
        </div>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    </div>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myPortfolio', ['ui.router', 'slick', 'ngAnimate', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.config(function ($stateProvider) {
  // An array of state definitions
  var states = [
    {
      name: 'about',
      url: '/about',
      component: 'about'
    },

    {
      name: 'projects',
      url: '/projects',
      component: 'projects',
      // It delegates to the ProjectService to HTTP fetch (async)
      // The project component receives this via its `bindings: `
      resolve: {
        projects: function (ProjectService) {
          return ProjectService.getAllProjects();
        }
      }
    },

    {
      name: 'project',
      // This state takes a URL parameter called projectId
      url: '/project/{projectId}',
      component: 'project',
      // This state defines a 'project' resolve
      // It delegates to the ProjectService, passing the projectId parameter
      resolve: {
        project: function (ProjectService, $transition$) {
          return ProjectService.getProject($transition$.params().projectId);
        }
      }
    }
  ]

  // Loop over the state definitions and register them
  states.forEach(function (state) {
    $stateProvider.state(state);
  });
});

myApp.config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
  // when there is an empty route, redirect to /index   
  $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/projects');

});

// preload the async data
myApp.run(function ($http) {
  $http.get('data/projects.json', { cache: true });
  $http.get('data/info.json', { cache: true });
});

//Make html in JSON file trusted
myApp.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
  return function (text) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
  };
}]);
```

**projects.js - component**

```
angular.module('myPortfolio').service('ProjectService', function($http) {
  var service = {
    getAllProjects: function() {
      return $http.get('data/projects.json', { cache: true }).then(function(resp) {
        return resp.data;
      });
    },

    getProject: function(id) {
      function projectMatchesParam(project) {
        return project.id === id;
      }

      return service.getAllProjects().then(function (projects) {
        return projects.find(projectMatchesParam)
      });
    }
  }

  return service;
})
```

**projects.js - service**

```
angular.module('myPortfolio').service('ProjectService', function($http) {
  var service = {
    getAllProjects: function() {
      return $http.get('data/projects.json', { cache: true }).then(function(resp) {
        return resp.data;
      });
    },

    getProject: function(id) {
      function projectMatchesParam(project) {
        return project.id === id;
      }

      return service.getAllProjects().then(function (projects) {
        return projects.find(projectMatchesParam)
      });
    }
  }

  return service;
})
```